# Passing calculated textbox values to an access db

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to send some textbox value to an access db using a query. 4 textboxes have calculated numeric values. While passing the value it shows the error **Conversion from string to type double is not valid**. Textbox 1,2,3,4 Have numeric values. This is my code:

```
Private Sub ok_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ok_button.Click
    provider1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile1 = "D:\electricity_billing.accdb"
    connString1 = provider1 & dataFile1
    myconnection1.ConnectionString = connString1
    myconnection1.Open()
    Dim str1 As String
    str1 = "Insert into 345([ID],[cust_name],[cust_add],[t_p_no],[nic],[email],[total_units],[amount],[adjustments],[due]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, myconnection1)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("cust_name", CType(name_textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("cust_add", CType(add_textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("t_p_no", CType(tp_textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("nic", CType(nic.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("email", CType(mail_textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("total_units", CDbl(TextBox1.Text)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("amount", CDbl(TextBox2.Text)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("adjustments", CDbl(TextBox4.Text)))
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("due", CDbl(TextBox3.Text)))
    Try
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd1.Dispose()
        myconnection1.Close()
        no_textbox.Clear()
        name_textbox.Clear()
        add_textbox.Clear()
        tp_textbox.Clear()
        nic.Clear()
        mail_textbox.Clear()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does this error occur?

Comment: There is no need to use CType to convert Textbox.Text to string because it **is** string.  However, rather than CDBL use `Double.TryParse` so you can catch cases where the value cannot converted

Comment: Have you tried setting a variable for each textbox value, then putting them into parameters this way? Eg; `Dim var1 as Double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(Textbox1.Text)` and then `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@due", OleDbType.Double).Value = var1`

Comment: @David can u please explain ur example with my code

Comment: It looks like you are not/have not validating the data.  You should not assume the user entered valid values everywhere.  Test the data using `Double.TryParse`

Comment: @Plutonix can u help me with a line of code how it want to be in the code i am new to vb

Comment: @RaziAngel That IS using your code. Just copy that in (And put it onto different lines where appropriate), and test if it works

Comment: @Plutonix no it is not working

Comment: Start with `Dim total_units as Double` and follow with `Double.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, total_units)`. Do this instead of the `CDbl` and do for each textbox you are attempting to convert. Then instead of passing `CDbl(TextBox1.Text)` to the parameter you can pass `total_units`. Further information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Note that `TryParse` will return false if the stuff in the textbox cant be converted to a double. You really ought to have a validation method to check the data *before* trying to update/insert - they are different steps.  Also hard to imagine why you are passing an ID when Access will assign one for you

Comment: @Jinx88909 it shows same error

Comment: I expected nothing less. This wasn't to fix the error but to work out which parameter was causing the error. Once you know which parameter is causing the error then you can debug the value that is being passed in. You're best stepping through your code and working out what values are being passed in. You need to validate data before it gets to this stage.